# Is there a command to restart computer into safe mode?

Tags: command-line, reboot, safe-mode

I would like to know if there is a command that could be written in the command line to restart the computer and make it boot in safe mode?

If there isn't a command like this, is there any other way to do it?

I would like the process to be fully automated after launching the command.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/55063/remote-restart-into-safe-mode-windows   it's not "simple".

Comment: And operating system is?

Comment: Operating system is windows server 2003, i forgot to mention, but i guess its obvious now that i have to change the boot.ini

Comment: Why was this question shut down? It has over 100,000 visits, and contains a question and it's correct answer..?? Please help me to understand why it is 'Off Topic' so I can avoid the same happening to me?

Comment: @Bevan: There is no indication that this is a _programming_ question. It would probably be a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

My first answer!

This will set the safemode switch:

```
bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
```

with networking:

```
bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network
```

then reboot the machine with

```
shutdown /r
```

to put back in normal mode via dos:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
```

Comment: also, your question might have been better posted at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This is only for _Vista_, _7_ and _Server 2008_. For earlier Windows versions look for [boot.ini](http://google.com/?q=boot.ini). For linux look for [grub](http://google.com/?q=grub+menu.lst).

Comment: What is replaced by {current} ?

Comment: In Windows 8.1 on a Sony Vaio laptop I had to use {default} instead of {current}. As noted in another answer type "bcdedit /enum" and find the identifier.

Answer (score 11):

In the command prompt, type the command below and press Enter.

```
bcdedit /enum
```

Under the Windows Boot Loader sections, make note of the identifier value.

To start in safe mode from command prompt :

```
bcdedit /set {identifier} safeboot minimal
```

Then enter the command line to reboot your computer.